# Asp.net application development on WIndows 32 bit and deployment on 64 bit

Tags: .net, asp.net, 32bit-64bit

I am working in an asp.net aplication which being developed on win 32 bit OS and the plan of deployment is win 64 bit environment. Do i need to take any prerequisite/precaution/steps in development or in deployment.  Please help.

Thanks/Yogesh

Comment: I'm a noob, but you might need to recompile it.  I cant think of much else you would need to do.

Comment: @Tom you shouldn't really need to do that if targeting any-CPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to do anything special, build for AnyCPU platform and it should work fine in both x86 and x64 machines, as long as you are not referencing external assemblies or libraries which run only on a specific architecture.

Answer (score 1):

*Generally* this works (assuming you target any-CPU and aren't using any PInvoke that could fall apart), however I wouldn't take that risk unless I have a test environment that matches production.

It may be more advisable, however, to just invest in 64-bit dev infrastructure to most closely mimic your target environment. Finding the problem *while you are writing it* is **far, far** cheaper than finding it even in test. And certainly cheaper than finding it in production.